# How to keep the search term in textbox even if any other actions

Tags: jquery, html

I want to keep the search term in the search box even some other access happen in that particular page.

**HTML**

```
<input id="search-mar" type="text" class="search reason" value="" placeholder="Search Markets">
```

If any other action happen like any button click any dropdown choose, the search term is clear. How to keep the search terms ?

Answer (score 0):

Try autocomplete on:

```
<input id="search-mar" type="text" class="search reason" value="" placeholder="Search Markets" autocomplete="on">
```

Comment: Any other ajax loading happen it is automatically clear.

Comment: Then try this one: localStorage.setItem("searchedVal", $("#search-mar").val());